# How to attach axios / axios interceptor to Nuxt globally ?

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

how would i go about attaching axios / axios interceptor globally to nuxt (so its available everywhere), same how i18n is attached ?

The idea is that i would like to have a global axios interceptor that every single request goes through that interceptor.

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you can create a plugin called axios (/plugins/axios.js)

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';

axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  // Do something before request is sent
  return config;
}, function (error) {
  // Do something with request error
  return Promise.reject(error);
});

Vue.use(axios);
```

then define this in nuxt.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
    //....

    plugins: [
      '~/plugins/axios',
    ],

    //....
};
```

thats all, your interceptor is now working globally

Comment: Is there any way to access state from this plugin?

Comment: yes, you can import the store und use it

`import store from '@/store/index';`
`store.getters['user/name'];`

in store you have to export getters, actions, etc

`export const getters = {
    name: (state, getters) => {...}
}`

Answer (score 9):

It's hidden in the documentation - https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins

See number 3 of the first photo:

```
// plugins/axios.js
export default function ({ $axios, redirect }) {
    $axios.onError(error => {
        if (error.response.status == 404) {
            redirect('/sorry')
        }
    })
}
```

then define this in nuxt.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    //....

    plugins: [
      '~/plugins/axios',
    ],

    //....
};
```

Comment: why plugin? why not middleware

Answer (score 4):

Maybe will be helpful for someone.
It just sets the lang parameter for every request.

Сreate a plugin called axios (/plugins/axios.js). Put it there:

```
export default function ({ $axios, app, redirect }) {
  $axios.onRequest(config => {
    config.params = config.params || {}; // get existing parameters
    config.params['lang'] = app.i18n.locale;
  })

  $axios.onError(error => {
    const code = parseInt(error.response && error.response.status)
    if (code === 400) {
      redirect('/400')
    }
  })
}
```

Add in nuxt.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
      '~/plugins/axios'
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a new module, call it request.js for example.

```
import axios from 'axios'
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://example.org' // if you have one
})

// Put all interceptors on this instance
instance.interceptors.response.use(r => r)

export default instance
```

Then simply import that instance whenever you need it and use it like it was a normal axios instance:

```
import request from './request'

await request.get('/endpoint')
// or use promises
request.get('/endpoint').then(data => data)
```

If you really need it globally you can use the following code in your entry point of the application:

```
import request from './request'
global.request = request
// use it:
await request.get('example.org')
```

Or you can add it to the vue protype

```
Vue.prototype.$request = request
// in your component:
this.$request.get()
```

I'd advice against it though.

Comment: id still have to import request module in every single component... is there a way to attach that to a global nuxt object ?

Comment: @rvsted yes you can, I've updated my answer accordingly but I don't suggest doing it, as the module import is just cleaner. You can also attach it to the vue instance by adding it to its prototype if you needed to.